# JSF 2: Create a custom component with CommandButton and get attribute to ActionListener

Tags: java, jsf, recursion, custom-component

I am new to Stack Overflow and have a question about JSF 2.0 and custom components (i use primefaces 3 too, buts not that important i think). Here is the situation: I have a nested data object  of type `AdvancedCriterion`, which contains a list of `AdvancedCriterion` or `Criterion` (via an interface `criteria`). These criterions are used to create a complex filter object like this:

- Advanced Criterion: AND

  - Criterion: PRODUCT equals "ABC"
  - Criterion: USER startswith "A"
  - AdvancedCriterion: OR

    - CRITERION: param1 > 5
    - CRITERION: param2 <= 20

I created two new components in Java: `AdvancedCriterion.java` and `SimpleCriterion.java` to do the recursion, because the first attempt to do it with a composite fails.  and recursive call of a composite in a composite creates a stack overflow :-(

Until know i can display a static filter object and it looks fine, but the user should add or delete criterions. So i addes some buttons (here came primefaces into it). Here some code, i started with the first criterion, which is always `AdvancedCriterion`.

```
<myTag:advancedCriteriaComponent criteria="#{manageFiltersBean.filterBuilder.criteria}" />
```

I create know the Button and want to give the parent object to the ActionListener:

```
CommandButton addButton = new CommandButton();
addButton.setId("btnAdd" + UUID.randomUUID());
addButton.setAjax(true);
addButton.setValue(" + ");
addButton.addActionListener(new CriteriaActionListener());
addButton.getAttributes().put("criteria", this.currentCriteria);
```

Well, and here comes the CriteriaActionListener:

```
@Override
    public void processAction(ActionEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
        AdvancedCriteria criteria = (AdvancedCriteria) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("criteria");
        criteria.addCriteria(new Criterion());
        System.out.println("number of children: " + criteria.getChildren().size());

    }
```

In the component the currentCriteria is well known and i can see his child-elements. In the `CriteriaActionListener` the object is empty (It has the right type, but looks like a fresh initalized object of this type) The question now: How could i get the `currentCriteria` Object into the `CriteriaActionListener`?

I tried a attribute in the ActionListener and set it from the component, then the whole object is NULL. I although tried to make an ELExpression and get it right to the bean (#{manageFiltersBean.addCriterion(criteria}) but the object is NULL. I have no more ideas and unfortunatly i am very new to JSF (about a few weeks).

Maybe it is about the id of the buttons? They are random, because the number of buttons is dynamic. I read, that every button must have an unique id to work properly. Or it is something about the attributes/params?

Thank you for your help,

Felix

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for putting together a finely worded question.  Is your project configured for `VIEW_STATE` on the client or on the server?  The reason I am asking is that your `criteria` object could be getting serialized and maybe not correctly because of the circular reference in that object (Eg. criteria -> childCriteria -> parentCriteria -> childCriteria, etc..).  Try removing the circular reference and see if your attribute is being passed in the ActionEvent then.

Comment: ... Oh and where is this CommandButton creation code occurring?  The constructor?  The render phase?  Implement the [BalusC Debug Phase Listener](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html) for more detailed logging on each JSF lifecycle phase.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @maple_shaft. I will try to answer your questions:

1) `CommandButton` is created in encodeBegin() method, this should be render phase.

2) The objects implements serialiable, but this was although an idea here. I will give it a try with the simpliest data object and reply later...

Comment: The render phase occurs **after** the Action (event) phase where you are looking in the event for the attribute. It may be that the Criterion object is getting set as an attribute for the button **after** the event occurs.  This could be another issue.

Comment: I had found the problem: The ActionListener was right, maybe the missing 'implements Serialiable' caused the problem too. But the main reason was, that somebody named the list of children 'criteriaList' and the getter for this 'getChildren' and not 'getCriteriaList'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is solved, some others occur. Well, like commented above, the problem was more like an problem with the implementation of the 'AdvancedCriteria' object. There was no connection or hint to the 'CommandButton', just a miss-named getter.

Probably the added line `implements Serialiable` helps although, I don't know exactly, because I tried a lot of things (save and restore states, enumeration propKeys with setters and getters and stuff like this), overall these weren't the solution.